# How to add HTML Page to Title bar of CRM account in MS CRM 2016 Online?

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created a functionality and added it in webresource as a HTML page. Now I want to add that HTML Page in one of following.

```
1- Title bar of CRM windows
or
2- In Activies or Records
```

Is it possible to add any of above? If so, please suggest how to add.
Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you can't change the title bar, but you should be able to add a link into the records section. You will need to [Edit the site map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309424.aspx).

Comment: I know how to add an entity in sitemap. Can you suggest me how to add HTML page(web resource) in the list shows when we click on "+"?

Comment: O sorry, didnt notice that was the quick create, I don't know if you can do that I'm afraid.

Comment: The only thing you can add to the quick create list is more entities for quick create, afaik.  And the only changes you can make to the title bar are changing the logo (images only) and the color scheme.